# Getting Response 200 or 'Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)' with Python GET Request

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to query a database, using python, with the documentation available here: https://www.ura.gov.sg/maps/api/#private-residential-property, whereby the output is supposed to be in JSON format. Below is my python code.

```
url = "https://www.ura.gov.sg/uraDataService/invokeUraDS?service=PMI_Resi_Transaction&batch=1"

query = {
    "AccessKey": "accesskey",
    "Token": "token"
}

response = requests.get(url=url, params=query)

print(response.json())
```

However, I'm getting an error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) instead of the values in JSON format.

using

```
print(response)
```

instead, i'm getting <Response [200]>.

Does anyone know where i went wrong?

Note: I have replaced 'accesskey' and 'token' with the actual accesskey and token.

Comment: Try to print the raw text and see how it looks first, `print(response.text)`. Maybe it's not a json response.

Comment: I'm getting html code with print(response.text). 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="errormain">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title></title>
<style>
    html,body,div{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    #some code
</script>
</body>
</html

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Aside for what @user56700 mentioned, you should always check the response status code before accessing the json() method.

Comment: you need either read api documents, or use browser dev tools to determine what part of http should the key and token go to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using
**Request** Package

import requests

```
    url = "https://www.ura.gov.sg/uraDataService/invokeUraDS?service=PMI_Resi_Transaction&batch=1"
    
    payload={}
    headers = {
      'AccessKey': 'accesskey',
      'Token': 'token',
'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.4',
      'Cookie': 'BIGipServerIAPP-HTTPS_A83-WWW.URA.GOV.SG_V4.app~IAPP-HTTPS_A83-WWW.URA.GOV.SG_V4_pool=!z0XVV5FkuQdCmN1CNQC8y2lWE3egLN/KKai61thY7Ni7WgSTHDm7rFYdZdydhkW3TPT1pit5ATmlEMU=; TS019d87de=01c9d36efc676e7a8a518d67985c9a128171baa74a24b4b25dee67ed071f25d6751f393ca9327f547898e23ec6d7702e73738d0b42'
    }
    
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    
    print(response.text)
```

.
**OR**

Standard **Http.client** package

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.ura.gov.sg")
payload = ''
headers = {
  'AccessKey': 'accesskey',
  'Token': 'token',
  'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.4',
  'Cookie': 'BIGipServerIAPP-HTTPS_A83-WWW.URA.GOV.SG_V4.app~IAPP-HTTPS_A83-WWW.URA.GOV.SG_V4_pool=!z0XVV5FkuQdCmN1CNQC8y2lWE3egLN/KKai61thY7Ni7WgSTHDm7rFYdZdydhkW3TPT1pit5ATmlEMU=; TS019d87de=01c9d36efc676e7a8a518d67985c9a128171baa74a24b4b25dee67ed071f25d6751f393ca9327f547898e23ec6d7702e73738d0b42'
}
conn.request("GET", "/uraDataService/invokeUraDS?service=PMI_Resi_Transaction&batch=1", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

**NB:** replace your **accesskey** and **token**. That provided by the gov site

**Tip:** Use the postman application. If you feel any confusion while using rest API .postman supplied most language and their HTTP library code. And they are available in the postman code section.

How to use restapi document with the postman(Gif  if you felt ugly gif .then click on the gif):

[image]

**PitFall and solution:**
Whenever we execute the API in postman work and return JSON. But using python code is not working and returns HTML (403 error).

In Jupyter Problem:
[image]

**Solution:**

[image]

Add this in headers:-

```
'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.4'
```

Comment: This works on Postman.API and i got the desired results on postman. When i run the 'Python - Requests' code on my jupyter notebook however, I'm getting <Response [200]>. Do you know why this may be the case?

Comment: i updated the code.you must check the code.i added ` 'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.4'` header variable

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code, printed the response.content:

```js
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="errormain">\n<head>\n<meta charset="UTF-8">\n<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\n<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">\n<title></title>\n<style>\n    html,body,div{padding: 0; margin: 0;}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n    <iframe id="autherframe" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://speresources.nexusguard.com/wafpage/index.html#403;121.15.15.162;4lAbdQAAAAAAAAAAeQ8PomnN;#403" width="100%"></iframe> \n<script>\nvar doc = document,\n    autherframe = doc.getElementById("autherframe");\n    var frameWin = autherframe.contentWindow;    //window\xe5\xaf\xb9\xe8\xb1\xa1  \n    var frameDoc = autherframe.contentWindow.document;  //document\xe5\xaf\xb9\xe8\xb1\xa1  \n    var frameBody = autherframe.contentWindow.document.body;   //body\xe5\xaf\xb9\xe8\xb1\xa1  \n    autherframe.onload = function(){\n        this.height = window.innerHeight>600?window.innerHeight:"600px";\n        this.scrolling = window.innerHeight>600?"no":"yes"\n    }\n</script>\n</body>\n</html'
```

which are not JSON data.

You can find the json() function explain [here](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).

--

Ok... I found in browser, the data is right. I added the headers to get func, works fine. You can try it~

```py
# User-Agent copied from Chrome.
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

resp = requests.get(url=url, params=query, headers=headers)
print(resp.content)
# b'{"Status":"Error","Message":"Invalid input.","Result":""}\r\n\r\n'
print(resp.json())
# {'Status': 'Error', 'Message': 'Invalid input.', 'Result': ''}
```

Comment: obviously, the OP want to get real data using the credentials. not the error json.